# Select elements with display:list-item

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select every third visible child of an ul. I tried to use :visible but don't get it to work. Is there another way of selecting elements with display:list-item? I figured :visible is only looking at display:block?

Comment: Elements are only considered to be hidden when their `display` is set to `none`, everything else is considered to be visible.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `nth-child`, it doesn't take into account the subset returned by `:visible` when determining its `nth` position.

You'll first need to select the visible ones, then do a `.filter()`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YNV3J/

```
$('ul > li:visible').filter(function(i) {
    return i % 3 === 2;
}).addClass('third');
```

---

**EDIT:** *Original answer was using `nth-child` which will fail in this situation. Fixed.*